# What is the acceptable range for mains voltages?

Tags: electrical

A watt meter told me that the voltage from my wall is 234V, while in Australia it's supposed to be 240V. Is this within the acceptable range? How much variation should I expect?

Comment: You meant a voltmeter, not a watt meter, but I understood what you meant. I will let someone from Australia answer your question. In the U.S., that voltage would be considered acceptable. A google search did yield this web site for Australia, but I don’t know if it is authoritative. https://www.energy.nsw.gov.au/sites/default/files/2022-08/2016_04_NSW_VoltageOptimisationFactsheet.pdf

Comment: @RobertJohnson -- most wattmeters these days can display voltage (whether they be utility smart meters or plug-in type consumer wattmeters such as a Kill-a-Watt)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel so wouldn’t that make it a multimeter?

Comment: @RobertJohnson -- technically speaking :P but they aren't multimeters in the traditional sense of the word (no ohms, for one)

Comment: It depends on current total load on the grid, so it will fluctuate, by about 3-5%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contract you sign with the power provider will tell you exactly, but one example is this:

Nominal voltage +10% -6%

Which means 240V plus 24V ie 264V max

And

240 minus 14.4V ie 225.6V minimum.

But check in the contract.

And we needed to know as setting inverters requires the max and min voltages.

Comment: It may be in a contract, or it may be in a national standard, but either way there's a range, and the minimum is likely to be less than 220V

Comment: @ChrisH So perhaps the supplier goes below its own limit - but who checks? And is there a duration applied ? 5 seconds? 5 minutes? 5 hours? Do they get fined? How often have you seen it? I know that one power co exceeded the max V specified as it was at the end of a long supply line - what happened? Nothing, because they were the ones that checked…

Comment: Standards aren't up to the supplier, but contracts are - with only one set of cables it's take it or leave it. But standards and regulators mean you're not reliant solely on (the threat of) legal action to get things fixed, unlike when specifications are purely contractual. That's one reason there are national safety standards behind those contracts. Our grid works really quite well. I can recall seeing a brownout once and that was over 6 years ago. Otherwise I get 235±2V whenever I check.

Comment: @ChrisH try checking at the end of the suppliers cable - like in mid Wales, they push the voltage up to overcome the losses…